# android Stripe amount not changing

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I am using stripe to process my payments. I noticed that it keeps charging only $14.00 and I wanted to know how can I change that to something $1.00. I tried modifying the `app.post("create-payment-intent")` and still nothing is changing. Every time I check my stripe dashboard I still see $14.00 being charged. I have a copy of my code. Can someone please assist me with this. Thanks in advance

```
//Code

 private void startCheckout() {

        //amount will calculate from .00 make sure multiply by 100
        //double amount=Double.parseDouble(mAmount.getText().toString())*1;

        // Create a PaymentIntent by calling the sample server's /create-payment-intent endpoint.
        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.get("application/json; charset=utf-8");

        /*
        String json = "{"
                + "\"currency\":\"usd\","
                + "\"items\":["
                + "{\"id\":\"photo_subscription\"}"
                + "]"
                + "}";

         */

        double amount=123.0;
        Map<String,Object> payMap=new HashMap<>();
        Map<String,Object> itemMap=new HashMap<>();
        List<Map<String,Object>> itemList =new ArrayList<>();
        payMap.put("currency","usd");
        payMap.put("amount","amount");
        itemMap.put("id","photo_subscription");
        itemMap.put("amount",amount);
        itemList.add(itemMap);
        payMap.put("items",itemList);
        String json = new Gson().toJson(payMap);
        //Log.i("TAG", "startCheckout: "+json);





        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType,json);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(BACKEND_URL + "create-payment-intent")
                .post(body)
                .build();
        httpClient.newCall(request)
                .enqueue(new PayCallback(this));




        // Hook up the pay button to the card widget and stripe instance
        //Button payButton = findViewById(R.id.payButton);
        payButton.setOnClickListener((View view) -> {
            //String get_card=cardInputWidget.getCard().getAddressZip();
            //Toast.makeText(PaymentPageActivity.this, get_card, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            PaymentMethodCreateParams params = cardInputWidget.getPaymentMethodCreateParams();
            if (params != null) {
                Map<String, String> extraParams = new HashMap<>();
                extraParams.put("setup_future_usage", "off_session");

                ConfirmPaymentIntentParams confirmParams = ConfirmPaymentIntentParams
                        .createWithPaymentMethodCreateParams(params, paymentIntentClientSecret);
                stripe.confirmPayment(this, confirmParams);
            }
        });
    }


//server.js

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const { resolve } = require("path");
// This is your real test secret API key.
const stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_****************");
app.use(express.static("."));
app.use(express.json());
const calculateOrderAmount = items => {
  // Replace this constant with a calculation of the order's amount
  // Calculate the order total on the server to prevent
  // people from directly manipulating the amount on the client
  return 100;
};
app.post("/create-payment-intent", async (req, res) => {
  const { items } = req.body;
  // Create a PaymentIntent with the order amount and currency
  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: calculateOrderAmount(items),
    currency: "usd"
  });
  res.send({
    clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret
  });
});
app.get("/greet", async (req, res) => {
 res.send('hello it is working');
});
const PORT= process.env.PORT || 5001;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('Node server listening on port $(PORT)'));
```

Comment: What is your BACKEND_URL pointing to? Is it possible you've made the changes to your server code locally, but your client code is not pointed to your local instance?

Comment: My backend url is pointed to https://stripe-p****-backend-backend.herokuapp.com/

Comment: And have you pushed your local server code changes to heroku?

Comment: Honestly idk I just followed everything I was told to do by this tutorial on youtube.[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QogamuVU6RM&list=PLVW1e1FvhW67aJ2alJePjwYtlivd8klv9]

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that your client code is pointing to a server that does not have your local changes. You have two options:

- Change your BACKEND_URL to point to your local server while your testing
- Leave your BACKEND_URL as is, commit and push your changes to master, and run `git push heroku master` to push your changes to heroku.

Comment: I notice that when I g on backend url it says cannot get/ is that the problem you're referring to?

Comment: Also when you say I change to my local server which is http://127.0.0.1:5001 it does not work

Comment: I should've specified - you would also have to run your server locally using `heroku local web`

Comment: Sorry for all the questions but how will I do that. I did run heroku local on the comand line but its says there is no such file. Am i doing this wrong?